UCB Logo question about behavior of equalp vs. =
I am working through Symbolic Computing (Harvey) and I found a behavior I don't understand.  I'm trying to write the color operation that outputs the color of a card from an input like 3h (3 of hearts).
I set "name with [make "name readlist] and then try this:  if last :name = "h [print "red"].  I get an error that if doesn't like e as input.
I executed print last :name = "h and it printed e!
I executed print equalp last:name "h and it printed True.
Why do I get e when I use =?
I wrote this in the previous box.
